# Find (apparently) open files from disconnect network share?

Tags: windows, networking, network-share, windows-10

Trying to disconnect a mapped network drive, I get the below error:

[image: network locations]

Error:

You currently have files open on X: (connected to \x.x.x.x\Share). If you don't close the files before disconnecting from the network device, you might lose data. Do you want to disconnect?

[image: Error: You currently have files open on X: (connected to \x.x.x.x\share). If you don't close the files before disconnecting from the network device, you might lose data. Do you want to disconnect?]

I've checked the "Open Files" section in computer management and it's blank, but the issue persists.  I've closed most programs, checked that I've closed any files that are located on this share, I've restarted explorer.exe.

[image]

This share contains essential work and if I've really got files open on this, then I need to know.  But how can I find out?  Is there a powershell / command prompt function that can list any open files by location?

Running Win 10 ver 21H1

Any help appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Just checking: did you check the "Open Files" section in computer management at remote machine (192.168. 3.7)? Or local machine? Or is it your local machine which holds the share?

Comment: The network drive is a server share.  I was trying to disconnect the drive from my local pc, and so I checked the "open files" section on my local pc.

Comment: Just click the Yes button.

Answer (score 2):

Two options for you:

- On client: download [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), run it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to look for handle `X:`. This will show you which file is used by which process
- On server: check "Open files" in the Computer Management. It will show files locked by your user account